# is it possible to build GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, software-design

I ran into an issue with my android design when my web hosting company doesn't allow GCM ports . so I was thinking about building my own "kinda GCM" to serve me. But, I need a starting point on building the receiver. so is it possible to build a service similar to GCM for and android app? and where to start researching ?

here is my php side to connect with GCM

```
<?php

/*
 * Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require it within a php script. Since we want this script to add a new user to our db, we will be talking with our database, and therefore, let's require the connection to happen:
 */
require ("config.inc.php");

// Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
$api_Key = "SERVER-API";

// Replace with the real client registration IDs
$registrationIDs = array ();

$data = array (
        'message' => 'Hello World!' 
);

// ------------------------------
// The recipient registration IDs
// that will receive the push
// (Should be stored in your DB)
//
// Read about it here:
// http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/
// ------------------------------

$ids ="ANDROID-DEVICE-GCM-ID";


// ------------------------------
// Call our custom GCM function
// ------------------------------

sendGoogleCloudMessage ( $data, $ids );

// ------------------------------
// Define custom GCM function
// ------------------------------
function sendGoogleCloudMessage($data, $ids) {
    // ------------------------------
    // Replace with real GCM API
    // key from Google APIs Console
    //
    // https://code.google.com/apis/console/
    // ------------------------------
    $api_Key = "AIzaSyCd88kVYixxkcOKbTShw4HHeYjMRbEWTWU";

    // ------------------------------
    // Define URL to GCM endpoint
    // ------------------------------

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    // ------------------------------
    // Set GCM post variables
    // (Device IDs and push payload)
    // ------------------------------

    $post = array (
            'registration_ids' => $ids,
            'data' => $data 
    );

    // ------------------------------
    // Set CURL request headers
    // (Authentication and type)
    // ------------------------------

    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . $api_Key,
            'Content-Type: application/json' 
    );

    // ------------------------------
    // Initialize curl handle
    // ------------------------------

    $ch = curl_init ();

    // ------------------------------
    // Set URL to GCM endpoint
    // ------------------------------

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    // ------------------------------
    // Set request method to POST
    // ------------------------------

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    // ------------------------------
    // Set our custom headers
    // ------------------------------

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

    // ------------------------------
    // Get the response back as
    // string instead of printing it
    // ------------------------------

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    // ------------------------------
    // Set post data as JSON
    // ------------------------------

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode ( $post ) );

    // ------------------------------
    // Actually send the push!
    // ------------------------------

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );

    // ------------------------------
    // Error? Display it!
    // ------------------------------

    if (curl_errno ( $ch )) {
        echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error ( $ch );
    }

    // ------------------------------
    // Close curl handle
    // ------------------------------

    curl_close ( $ch );

    // ------------------------------
    // Debug GCM response
    // ------------------------------

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be *far* simpler for you to switch to a better host.

Comment: is there any host out there that allow additional ports ?! they all ask you to switch to VHS ... which is more expansive and unaffordable.

Comment: let me make my question more clear.
"can I make a connection between my app and the server (say I know which port is open from my website) where this connection allow my to send notifications"

Comment: "is there any host out there that allow additional ports ?!" -- I don't know what you mean. You need *outbound* access from your server to the GCM servers, not *inbound*. I would expect few Web hosts to have issues with that, and if they do, you can always run a VPS, or an Amazon micro EC2 instance, or use Google App Engine. Your Web host isn't going to let you have the thousands (or millions) of open socket connections that you would need to roll your own, and making such a solution reliable and battery efficient will take a very long time.

Comment: VPS*, sorry. So, you are saying I should get a VPS, and host my web side of my application in there using WAMP or any similar ones like it?!

Comment: GCM (at least the HTTP endpoint) requires the default https port (443) to be open. I find it hard to believe that any web hosting company would block that port. The other ports that GCM requires - 5228-5230 - are only required for the device to connect to GCM server over WiFi, which has nothing to do with the hosting company.

Comment: look for error 401 "Unauthorized" in stack overflow. a lot of people actually have this issue.

Comment: I would start by finding a Web host not run by drooling idiots. If your server is trying to communicate with other Web services, those communications should work over HTTPS, and hence 443 should be unblocked. A VPS, Amazon EC2 instance, or Google App Engine are among the other alternatives.